# ruby-amqp and rspec messaging cleaner

Tags: ruby, amqp

I am currently working on a messaging system with ruby-amqp, for testing I am using rspec.
If a test fails, I still have messages in queues after the test is finished. Is there a way to clean up all queues like the database_cleaner gem does it for databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may delete the whole queue with  [AMQP::Queue#delete](http://rubydoc.info/github/ruby-amqp/amqp/master/AMQP/Queue#delete-instance_method)

Just take the AMQP::Queue instance and call

```
queue.delete
```

or

```
queue.delete do |_|
  puts "Deleted #{queue.name}"
end
```